# Powershell Script to Extract Text from Multiple Lines into Single Line

Tags: powershell

I am needing to extract some text lines from a text file via powershell to a new output file based on some criteria and then also extract some data of the next line into the same line.

This is a sample of the text file:

```
0 CARDHOLDER NUMBER     TOKEN NUMBER          MESSAGE DATE/TIME    ACTIVITY REASON            NTWK   PAN EXP  TRAN ID                
0 1234567890123456      4234567890123456      11/12/14  15:34:38   T1-TKN CREATE              VSN     49/12   314316099993286        
     TOKEN DATA: EXP DATE: 16/05   REQUESTOR ID: 45432112345   TYPE: T0   STATUS: I   ASSURANCE LEVEL: 16   REQUEST METHOD: 6        
                 TOKEN REF ID: TOKENREFERENCEDATAID012345678901 PAN REF ID: PANREFERENCEID                                           
          TERMS: VERSION: Terms and condition verification data                           DATE/TIME: Mon, 07 Apr 2014 10:25:217      
   TEXT MESSAGE: $TM*TOKEN NOTIFICATION ADVICE                                                                                       
0 5678901234561234      4234567890123456      11/12/14  15:34:44   T2-TKN DEACTIVATE          VSN     49/12   314316100043288        
     TOKEN DATA: EXP DATE: 16/05   REQUESTOR ID: 45432112345   TYPE: T0   STATUS: I   ASSURANCE LEVEL: 16   REQUEST METHOD: 6        
                 TOKEN REF ID: TOKENREFERENCEDATAID012345678901 PAN REF ID: PANREFERENCEID                                           
          TERMS: VERSION: Terms and condition verification data                           DATE/TIME: Mon, 07 Apr 2014 10:25:217      
   TEXT MESSAGE: $TM*TOKEN NOTIFICATION ADVICE
```

The desired output would get the Cardholder Number and Requestor ID into a single line like:

```
1234567890123456,45432112345 
5678901234561234,45432112345
```

Right now I have the following code but it doesn't pull the substring from the next line but rather than line with the card number:

```
$report = get-content $inputFile

foreach ($line in $report) { 
    if ($line -match 'T5-DEVICE PRV RSLT') {
        $card = $line.Substring(2,16)
        $lineRequestor = $line + 1
        $requestorID = $lineRequestor.SubString(49,11)
        if ($card.StartsWith("4")) {
            $card = $card + ','
            $output = $card + $requestorID
            $output | out-file -FilePath $outputFile -Append
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So records in the file start with a `0` in the first column (with the exception of the header line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following simplified `Select-String` based solution identifies the two pieces of data to extract by the number of digits they contain (`16` and `11`, respectively).

```
# Search for lines with cardholder numbers and include one line below
# (-Context 0, 1)
Select-String '\b\d{16}\b' $inputFile -Context 0,1 | ForEach-Object { 
  # Match the requestor ID on the line below.
  $null = $_.Context.PostContext[0] -match '\b\d{11}\b';
  # Output the cardholder number found by Select-String and the
  # requestor ID found with -match
  $_.Matches[0].Value + ',' + $Matches[0] 
} # | Set-Content $outputFile
```

<sup>Remove the `#` to save to `$outputFile`.</sup>

With your sample input file this yields:

```
1234567890123456,45432112345
5678901234561234,45432112345
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$lineRequestor = $line + 1`

Instead of getting the next input line, this performs *string concatenation* with the current line and appends `'1'` to it.

Generally, **you can't (easily) skip ahead in an enumeration being performed by a `foreach` loop**.<sup>[1]</sup>

If you wanted to do that, **use a `for` loop with *indices***, as in the following simplified example:

```
$lines = 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.Count; ++$i) {
  # Output a pair of lines.
  "item + next item: " + $lines[$i] + ', ' + $lines[++$i]
}
```

---

<sup>[1] Technically, you can, but the solution is obscure, via the automatic `$foreach` variable:

`foreach ($line in 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four') { $null = $foreach.MoveNext(); $nextLine = $foreach.Current; "$line - $nextLine" }`</sup>

Comment: I was able to use your $foreach code with my code to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that records start with a digit `0` through `9` followed by a whitespace character and at least one more digit in the first column, here is a sample script that might work for you:

```
$inputData = @"
0 CARDHOLDER NUMBER     TOKEN NUMBER          MESSAGE DATE/TIME    ACTIVITY REASON            NTWK   PAN EXP  TRAN ID                
0 1234567890123456      4234567890123456      11/12/14  15:34:38   T1-TKN CREATE              VSN     49/12   314316099993286        
    TOKEN DATA: EXP DATE: 16/05   REQUESTOR ID: 45432112345   TYPE: T0   STATUS: I   ASSURANCE LEVEL: 16   REQUEST METHOD: 6        
                TOKEN REF ID: TOKENREFERENCEDATAID012345678901 PAN REF ID: PANREFERENCEID                                           
          TERMS: VERSION: Terms and condition verification data                           DATE/TIME: Mon, 07 Apr 2014 10:25:217      
  TEXT MESSAGE: $TM*TOKEN NOTIFICATION ADVICE                                                                                       
0 5678901234561234      4234567890123456      11/12/14  15:34:44   T2-TKN DEACTIVATE          VSN     49/12   314316100043288        
    TOKEN DATA: EXP DATE: 16/05   REQUESTOR ID: 45432112346   TYPE: T0   STATUS: I   ASSURANCE LEVEL: 16   REQUEST METHOD: 6        
                TOKEN REF ID: TOKENREFERENCEDATAID012345678901 PAN REF ID: PANREFERENCEID                                           
          TERMS: VERSION: Terms and condition verification data                           DATE/TIME: Mon, 07 Apr 2014 10:25:217      
  TEXT MESSAGE: $TM*TOKEN NOTIFICATION ADVICE                                                                                       
"@ -split [Environment]::NewLine

& {
  foreach ( $row in $inputData ) {
    $outputRow = $false
    if ( $row -match '^\d\s\d+' ) {
      $cardHolderNumber = [Regex]::Match($row,'^\d\s(\d+)').Groups[1].Value
    }
    elseif ( $row -match 'REQUESTOR ID: \d+' ) {
      $requestorID = [Regex]::Match($row,'REQUESTOR ID: (\d+)').Groups[1].Value
      $outputRow = $true
    }
    if ( $outputRow ) {
      [PSCustomObject] @{
        "CardHolderNumber" = $cardHolderNumber
        "RequestorID"      = $requestorID
      }
    }
  }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The `$inputData` variable can be replaced by `Get-Content` to read the input file. The output of the above script is:

```
"CardHolderNumber","RequestorID"
"1234567890123456","45432112345"
"5678901234561234","45432112346"
```

Comment: This did get me the output of card number and requestor ID however I am needing to only get the card numbers where 'T5-DEVICE PRV RSLT' appear in the line with the card number.  It would be in the location where 'T1-TKN CREATE' and 'T2-TKN DEACTIVATE' appear in the examples I gave you.  The sample data I provided didn't include a record in which I would have actually like to have returned I see now.  How can I go about only returning those rows.  In addition, if I wanted a different output file for each requestor id with only those card numbers in each file how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can use the sample code in my answer (or possibly the other answer) to construct a solution that works for your scenario. (I would note that your original question does not include the details you have in your comment here, so I would recommend updating your question.)